# What is the difference between <router-link> and $router.push?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

`<router-link>` in my opinion takes more work to implement, since you can add `$router.push` to any element with an `@click` event.

What are the pros and cons of each approach? Is there any instance, where `<router-link>` can not be replaced by `$router.push`?

Answer (score 5):

While `router-link`'s handler does the same `$router.push()`, it also performs under the hood a handful of useful actions that you will have to implement by yourself to assure the navigation works as expected in every scenario. For example, it activates a "navigation guard" to check for the validity of the triggering event, catches any navigation errors, also, it is the implementation of active route detection and styling which may be a pain to implement in complex navigations (for ex. multilevel navigation menus) that is also simplified by the `router-link` implementation.
These are some of the pros that I could spot at a first glance at its source code. You can look at it for a more in depth comparison [here](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/src/RouterLink.ts)

Answer (score 1):

First of all  is a tag like a tag in HTML so you can not use it inside your script tags. You can only use it inside  tags. You have to give **to** attribute to **router-link** and you do not need to use click etc.

However, for bigger projects sometimes you need to redirect to another page after you submit a form, or anywhere you like to use redirection in your js. That's why there is **$router.push**, the **$router** object is vue-router object so you have all functions that vue-router serves you.